# Node.js and express and production ssl certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having problems with implement SSL certificate using node.js.

Everything works fine with localhost, but as soon as I move to Ubuntu server, multiple problems occur.

I've minimized to the following code.
Certificates (.crt) and keys (.key) are in the certificates directory, with names like localhost.key or exampleSSLServer.crt.
I'm using a RapidSSL certificate and was told I needed to also include the intermediate certificate.

```
function serverSSL(host,port,intermediate) {
    var https   = require('https');
    var fs      = require('fs');
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var httpsOptions = {
        key:  fs.readFileSync('certificates/' + host + '.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certificates/' + host + '.crt')
    };
    if (intermediate) {
        httpsOptions.ca = [fs.readFileSync('certificates/' + intermediate + '.crt')];
    }
    var server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app).listen({
        port:  port,
        host: host
    }, initServer);

    function initServer() {
        var host = server.address().address,
            port = server.address().port;
        console.log(
          'Example app listening at https://%s:%s', host, port);
    }

    app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
        var msg = 'Hello SSL';
        console.log(msg);
        res.send(msg);
    });
}
```

I've tried two different calls either

1. serverSSL('localhost',8445);
2. serverSSL('exampleSSLServer.com',8445,'intermediate')

localhost works fine, but when I use my server, I get the following stack error:

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 52.xxx.xxx.xxx:8445
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at net.js:1395:9
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:64:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:83:10)
```

If I take out the host argument, then it doesn't fail, but it also doesn't respond.
I changed the code slight to use http vs. https and things seem to work fine.
Also, I've tried many different ports, the same problem occurs.

Their might be a problem with my SSL certificate, but I have no easy way to debug it.  I'd be happy to try another tool.

In any case, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I got the following from CheapSSL Security (cheapsslsecurity.com)

Hello,

With the prices we offer we cannot support Node.js. 
Its up to the sysadmin to configure and install the Certificate correctly. 
RapidSSL I highly doubt will give technical support for Node.js as its a tricky installation.


regards,
Paul

Glad to know they stand by their products.